# What spider is this in Idaho?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology, invertebrates

I have killed maybe 5 of these solders as I have a 3 year old and dont want her bit.

Details :

- Whitish top; brown legs; striped maybe yellow or white on the butt with black
- Size of a penny
- Seen them all times of the day. Summer (July)

Kinda reminds me of the ant-mimic spider but I am unsure.

[image]

And a close up:

[image]

Should be able to zoom in quite a bit. Just hold CTRL and hit the plus symbol.

Comment: First thought that comes to mind is a [Parson Spider](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/parsons_spider_kit.jpg), but not quite.. the fact that there's a blemish on the plastic of your vacuum cleaner (lol) makes it a bit difficult to assess the full pattern on the abdomen of the spider.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just about 100% certain that this is a [Hobo Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobo_spider), which belongs to the species *Eratigena agrestis*. As stated in my comment, the blemish on the vacuum cleaner's plastic makes it difficult to observe the full pattern on the spider's abdomen, which would have otherwise made for a much quicker identification.

Once realized though, the distinguishing feature for me was in fact the pattern on the abdomen. If you look at the picture I provide and consider at the abdomen, it looks like a face with two eyes, a mouth, some hair, and a beard; i.e., a hobo. Now look at the picture in the OP -- the exact same "face" can be seen, excluding the right "eye" of the hobo (our left), due to the blemish on the vacuum's plastic. The "hair" at the pedicel, the down-turned "mouth", and the "beard", are all visible in both images, and are near perfect matches. The legs, overall body coloration, size & proportionalities, and slight discoloration on the cephalothorax, also match.

*I had to maximize the OPs image to 200% zoom to get a detailed enough view of the spider to then make these conclusions.*

[image]

This species spider is most commonly found in your region, that being north west USA, however, they've also been seen in Asia and Europe. And as for if this is a venomous spider (since you're concerned about your daughter): according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobo_spider#Toxicity_and_aggression), this kind of spider doesn't bite unless forced to defend itself, and, the CDC does not consider it to be dangerously venomous.

[image]

Comment: Well written post. Thanks. However, as [Toothpasta mentions in their post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/88389), your image is actually of *Sergiolus montanus* (the stealthy ground spider). Your own wiki link will also confirm this isn't the hobo spider. I would advise adding an update to your answer acknowledging this mistake and perhaps sharing the range and danger status of the *correct* spider species. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If user22020 is 100% sure that's a hobo spider, then I'm 101% sure that's a [stealthy ground spider](https://www.invasive.org/browse/subthumb.cfm?sub=56180). The source of user22020's picture actually labeled it as such. 
[image]
 It's definitely in the ground spider family, just like Parsons spiders.

Hobo spiders and barn funnelweavers are more well-known, but both are brown, not black and white, and have vastly different patterning than yours. Stealthy ground spider are not famous because they, like most Idaho spiders, are not dangerous.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Can you elaborate why you think your identification is correct? For example, discuss the key features that helped you come to this conclusion and provide references that support your assertions. ——— You might also want to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] questions effectively on this site and then edit your answer accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a male barn funnel weaver, according to a quick google search. The main part of this picture that leads me to believe that is the first segment of the leg, closest to the body, is darker than the rest. [image: Funnel Weaver]
This is the a male barn funnel weaver, with the same darker segments. And yes, I looked at the list specifically for Idaho

Comment: Answers to species ID questions need a lot more content than this. You need to convince us that your ID is correct, explain why that ID applies over other IDs, and hopefully provide some convincing pictures. Note that species ID is quite difficult, especially for arthropods due to incredible diversity and many similar body plans for distinct species (and even genera).